# Can't start Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, asus

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my ASUS 1025C, and when the installation finished, usually it restarts, but suddenly it displays a purple screen and the screen turns off, but the computer is still working. I can't do anything, because the screen is always off.

Any help?

Comment: can you include your PC specifications ? especially VGA card ? AMD , Nvidia or Intel ?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get 12.10 working on the 1025c. There are a number of articles/forum posts indicating that it is not recommended and maybe not possible due to closed source drivers and the integrated graphics. 12.04 is working fine for me but required some tweaking and scripts to get suspend and the brightness keys working. I suggest sticking with 12.04. With a ssd and upgraded RAM, 12.04 performance is acceptable and battery life is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted to make sure that the disk is supposed to launch whenever you start your computer by putting a tag on it.